# Whole widget freezes/doesn't load when trying self.after() in Tkinter

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a simple window showing a bit of text that is quickly changing between the three primary colours. When I try this code, the window doesn't load for a few seconds, then the text just appears red, rather than changing. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

PRIMARY = ("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF")


class Multicolour(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.txt = Label(self,
                         text="Colour change")
        self.txt.grid()
        self.colour_index = 0
        for i in range(3000):
            self.after(10, self.change)

    def change(self):
        self.txt.configure(fg=PRIMARY[self.colour_index])
        self.colour_index += 1
        if self.colour_index > 2:
            self.colour_index = 0


root = Tk()
app = Multicolour(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're causing `change` to be called 3000 times in a row, all starting after 10ms. Not 10ms from each other, but 10ms from the time the loop starts. Is that really what you're intending to do?

Comment: I'm happy to accept a 10ms wait before the first `change` happens, and then I want a 10ms gap between each change of colour.